# How would i make it so that a div hides in a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a wackamole game and I want the mole (a div) to only stay viewable for a certain amount of time. Is there any way that I can do this wit javascript

```html
<div class="mole">mole</div>
```

Comment: use settimeout callback

Comment: could you put an answer down so that I know how to do that, I am still learning javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTimeout(function, delay)`

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("mole")[0].style.display = 'none';  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="mole">mole</div>
```

Note that it might be good to give your element an id, that way you can target the element directly. Now I'm just picking the first (and in the example the only) element with the `mole` class.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you maybe leave an up vote on this so that i can get my student badge, i have been trying to get that for a while

Comment: appreciate it. @baao

Comment: @baao do you think it doesn't have duplicate ?

Comment: hey i wanted an answer just for this game i am making

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)`
where

**function** - Required. The function that will be executed

**milliseconds** - Optional. The number of milliseconds to wait before executing the code. If omitted, the value 0 is used

**param1,param2,...** - Optional. Additional parameters to pass to the function (Not supported in IE9 and earlier)

```js
  
  setTimeout(function(){ $(".mole").hide() }, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mole">mole</div>
```